# Assignment operators performance issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to know if there are any differences in between the assignment operators ,`=` and `:=` in Oracle plsql.

some times i got results faster from only equal sign rather than using `:=`. Are there cases where they can give different results or different performance?

Answer (score 2):

```
:= assignment operator
=  relational operator
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/02_funds.htm

Example:

```
1) IF a = b THEN

2) l_variable NUMBER := 10;
```

The delimiters are used in a different way, you cannot replace one with the other.